# client-go get configMap issue

Tags: go, kubernetes, client-go

I am trying to create a simple deployment on Kubernetes using client-go. Following the [example](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/tree/master/examples/in-cluster-client-configuration), I am creating the `inClusterConfig` for the client. Also, I have created a `role` and a `roleBinding` for deployment SA to get, list and watch ConfigMap objects.

When using the `Client.Get()`, I am getting
`Get "https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/default/configmaps": Access Denied`

Tried to exec into the pod and with
curl https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/default/configmaps with the token mounted in
/var/run/secrets/..../token i was able to get the CM

any idea ?

also have created corresponding role and rolebinding

```yaml
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - configmaps
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch

roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: got-dynamic-cm-reader-Role
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: got
  namespace: default
```

Answer (score 0):

In the example that you have mentioned, the service account that has been created has only cluster `viewer` role, which is insufficient if you are trying to create resources.

Try binding an `admin` role binding to the service account. But, for production purposes, you should use a more granular approach on adding permissions to the service account.

Comment: i have create a ServiceAccount and bounded the specific permission to get list watch the config map :

rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - configmaps
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch